# Override the ContractResolver in json.net at property lvl

Tags: json, json.net

```
public class GDALInfoResult
    {
        public GDALInfoResult()
        {
            MetaData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        }

        public Dictionary<string, string> MetaData { get; set; }


    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = new GDALInfoResult()
            {

            };
            result.MetaData["EXIF_TestSomthing"] = "Hello";

            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() }));

        }
    }
```

The above code will print out:

```
{
  "metaData": {
    "exiF_TestSomthing": "Hello"
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can override the MetaData property such its not using the `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` that is specified in the Console Write Line ?

I dont want it to change names in my MetaData property, but cannot change teh serialization settings used in the serialize object. (of cause I can in this demo, but thats just to show my problem).

Comment: You don't want to change `MetaData` or the keys of the dictionary? Or both?

Comment: I dont want "EXIF_" to become "exiF"

Answer (score 0):

The following does the trick, but seams like a lot of extra code to do it. Works, if no one else comes up with a better solution.

```
   public class IgnoreSettingsConverter : JsonConverter
    {

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
           return true;
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            var s = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
            s.Serialize(writer, value);
        }
    }
    public class GDALInfoResult
    {
        public GDALInfoResult()
        {
            MetaData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        }

        [JsonConverter(typeof(IgnoreSettingsConverter))]
        public Dictionary<string, string> MetaData { get; set; }


    }
```